24.04.1 LTS - Some keyboard shortcuts stopped working
I don't know what triggered this but after some restarts, some of the keyboard shortcuts do not work.
For example, normally I open guake with F12 and now this isn't working. However, Ctrl+Alt+T is working properly.
I can copy and paste text with keyboard shortcuts without any issues.
Another thing that's not working is my Ctrl+Shift+V shortcut that I assigned to opening the clipboard menu for CopyQ.
I can define custom keyboard shortcuts from the settings to open and close guake but it doesn't operate same as before. Normally it would open the terminal in the display that my mouse is active but if I define it as a custom shortcut with a command, it would always open on the main display.
So what I think is somehow my applications that are running as pinned to the gnome, can't register their own keyboard shortcuts to the gnome.
When I viewed gnome logs and filtered for copyq these logs show up:
09:17:06 copyq: Warning: Failed to set global shortcut "Ins" for command "Show the tray menu".
09:17:06 copyq: Warning: Failed to set global shortcut "Ins" for command "Show the tray menu".
09:17:06 copyq: Warning: Failed to set global shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+V" for command "Show the tray menu".
09:17:06 copyq: ERROR: [default] QtCritical: Failed to activate Wayland clipboard
09:17:06 copyq: Warning: [default] QtWarning: Activating Wayland clipboard took 5000 ms
09:16:59 copyq: Warning: [default] QtWarning: QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
09:16:59 systemd: Started app-gnome-copyq-5810.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.


And these are the results for guake:
09:17:14 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1734416234.042:258): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/guake/autostart-guake.desktop" pid=5919 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
09:17:14 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1734416234.042:258): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/guake/autostart-guake.desktop" pid=5919 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
09:17:14 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1734416234.013:257): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/guake/autostart-guake.desktop" pid=5919 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
09:17:02 guake: Guake initialized
09:17:02 guake: Guake initialized
09:17:02 guake: Guake tabs restored from /home/cagdasalagoz/.config/guake/session.json
09:17:02 systemd: Started vte-spawn-8e979882-df3f-47c8-8bb5-546675ba7e3f.scope - VTE child process 6622 launched by guake process 5749.
09:17:02 guake: Spawning new terminal at /home/cagdasalagoz
09:17:02 guake: Spawning new terminal at /home/cagdasalagoz
09:17:02 guake: can't bind show-focus key
09:17:02 guake: current workspace is 0
09:17:02 systemd: Started vte-spawn-696ec79c-f7ce-4c5d-aa7f-efabf91d8099.scope - VTE child process 6594 launched by guake process 5749.
09:17:02 guake: Spawning new terminal at /home/cagdasalagoz
09:17:02 guake: Spawning new terminal at /home/cagdasalagoz
09:17:02 guake: created fresh notebook for workspace 0
09:17:02 guake: Gtk 3.24.41
09:17:02 guake: VTE 0.76.0
09:17:02 guake: Guake Terminal 3.10
09:17:01 guake: Language previously loaded from: /usr/share/locale
09:17:01 guake: Loading Gnome schema from: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
09:17:01 guake: Guake not running, starting it
09:16:59 systemd: Started app-gnome-guake-5749.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.



I had the same issue. I found the only one way to resolve it: set custom shortcut from settings.
screenshoot

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
